# AdChoicesView deprecated in Facebook ads any replacement

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-ads

AdChoicesView deprecated in Facebook ads any replacement

```
import com.facebook.ads.AdChoicesView;
  AdChoicesView adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(context, nativeAd, true);
                    viewHolder.adChoice = adChoicesView;
 viewHolder.nativeadview.addView(adChoicesView, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Facebook documentation for [AdChoicesView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reference/android/com/facebook/ads/adchoicesview.html/?version=v5.6.1):

> Deprecated.  since 5.1
>
> @Deprecated public class AdChoicesView extends RelativeLayout
>
> Please use AdOptionsView instead. An expandable, clickable ad choices
> icon. Can be added to a custom NativeAd view to signify ad content.

is replaced with [AdOptionsView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reference/android/com/facebook/ads/adoptionsview.html/?version=v5.5.0):

> public class AdOptionsView extends
> com.facebook.ads.internal.api.AdComponentView
>
> A clickable Ad Options icon, which presents the user with options to
> report and hide an ad. Should be added to Native Ads to present the
> users with these options.

You can create an `AdOptionsView` like the below:

```
AdOptionsView adOptionsView = new AdOptionsView(context, nativeAdBase, nativeAdLayout);  
addView(adOptionsView);
```

You can define extra params, such as the orientation of the icons in the view and the size of the icons like:

```
AdOptionsView adOptionsView = new AdOptionsView(context, nativeAdBase, nativeAdLayout, orientation, iconSizeDp);  
addView(adOptionsView);
```

To change the colors and the size of the icon:

```
AdOptionsView adOptionsView = new AdOptionsView(context, nativeAdBase, nativeAdLayout);   
adOptionsView.setIconColor(newColor);  
adOptionsView.setIconSizeDp(newIconSizeDp);  
addView(adOptionsView);
```

The above Parameters are:

`context` - The application context.

`nativeAdBase` - The native ad base.

`nativeAdLayout` - The native ad layout.

`orientation` - The orientation you want the icons to be in: horizontal or vertical.

`iconSizeDp` - The required icon size in dp - this will be converted to pixels.